# Django: Send SMTP Email in dev environment

Tags: django, email, smtp, office365, openoffice.org

I am trying to set up my app to send emails from office365 email offered by GoDaddy. There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771497/django-send-smtp-email-through-godaddy) but apparently the settings are not working. I have used the [settings here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) as well and I get `Service unavailable` error when I try sending an email.

My settings.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@******.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I get

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /contact-us/
Service unavailable
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. I used the `ping smtp.office365.com` it returned `outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com` as the DNS name. Using this host with my full office365 email address and password worked!

Settings

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'outlook-namnorth.office365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@******.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

`dig smtp.office365.com` returns a bunch of hosts, I guess depending on location.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> smtp.office365.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12153
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 14, AUTHORITY: 7, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;smtp.office365.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
smtp.office365.com. 269 IN  CNAME   smtp.outlook.office365.com.
smtp.outlook.office365.com. 269 IN  CNAME   outlook.office365.com.
outlook.office365.com.  294 IN  CNAME   outlook.ha.office365.com.
outlook.ha.office365.com. 3 IN  CNAME   outlook-    emeasouth2.office365.com.
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.7.194
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.44.138
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.6.90
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.55.210
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.29.114
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.5.130
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.4.2
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.96.33.178
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  132.245.55.178
outlook-emeasouth2.office365.com. 273 IN A  40.101.54.114
```